# How to add trigger for Task Scheduler on weekdays on a specific time, except for a certain days

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

So I have this .bat file that I need to run on weekdays at 1 pm. Adding it is easy, the problem is. Every 1st to 3rd day of the month(ex. January 1 to 3) the 1 pm run must not run but instead, it would need to run at 3 pm. I hope you can help me, thanks.